# How to group several lists of object into one list using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Using .net 6 I have 4 arrays of the following class

```
public class OrganisationConfigurationWrapper 
    {
        public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
        public OrganisationConfiguration Settings { get; set; }
    }
```

So they will be like

```
OrganisationConfigurationWrapper[] type1;
OrganisationConfigurationWrapper[] type2;
OrganisationConfigurationWrapper[] type3;
OrganisationConfigurationWrapper[] type4;
```

What I would like to do is join these together to produce a new list or array with these properties

```
{
        public Guid TenantId;
        public SettingsType[] AllSettings;
}

public class SettingsType
{
        public OrganisationConfiguration Settings;
        public string TypeName;
}
```

e.g. TenantId: 1 might have settingsType values of types: type1 and type2 whereas TenantId: 2 might have values for something totally different

I'm struggling a bit to think how to do all this in linq, and was wondering whether I need to fallback to a query that gets all the unique TenantIds across the 4 lists and then does a for loop over them and a lookup in each array to populate the settingsType array?

Comment: Where does SettingsType.TypeName come from? Do we need to see OrganisationConfiguration to understand that?

Comment: @jazza what is the final output u want

Comment: @Ralf - in my example it is "Type1", "Type2", Type3" or "Type4" depending on which array it was in originally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that TypeName is hardcoded in your case:

```cs
var query = 
    type1.Select(w => new { SettingsType = new SettingsType{ Settings = w.Settings, TypeName = "Type1" }, w.TenantId })
    .Concat(type2.Select(w => new { SettingsType = new SettingsType{ Settings = w.Settings, TypeName = "Type2" }, w.TenantId }))
    .Concat(type3.Select(w => new { SettingsType = new SettingsType{ Settings = w.Settings, TypeName = "Type3" }, w.TenantId }))    
    .Concat(type4.Select(w => new { SettingsType = new SettingsType{ Settings = w.Settings, TypeName = "Type4" }, w.TenantId }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.TenantId)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        TenantId = g.Key,
        AllSettings = g.Select(x => x.SettingsType).ToArray()
    });
```